# LLVM-IR array pointer assignment

Tags: c++, c, pointers, llvm, llvm-ir

In C++/C you can do this:

```
unsigned char A[12];
unsigned int *B;
int *C;
B = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
C = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
A[0] = *B;
A[4] = *C;
//Then go on to access A byte by byte.
```

I was wondering if this was possible in LLVM-IR, or would it immediately complain of a problem with types. Was about to dive into this, but thought I would see if anyone has tried this particular example. Would I GEP A's 0th location as a i8* and then B and C's as a i32*. I'm a bit confused as how to proceed, if this is at all possible.

Thanks ahead of time.

UPDATE:

Ok, if I instead added initialization for *B and C[0], C[1], it would the answer change for LLVM-IR /C / C++?

Comment: Assuming you fix the bit about not initializing `*B` and `C[0]` and `C[1]`, all this does is take the `unsigned int` (or `int` respectively) pointed to by `B` or `C`, truncate it to `char` size, and assign it to a slot in the `A` array. You should get a warning about loss of precision, assuming you aren't ignoring all warnings, but due to the standard conversions between integral types, this is legal, if somewhat questionable...

Comment: @twalberg; Thanks, that makes sense/ I was assuming that since there was continuous memory I could get away with placing the larger type into the array. and have the bits extended across A's allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM has the `bitcast` instruction which is often used to convert one type of pointer to another type of pointer - e.g., `i32*` to `i8*`.

So for example, if you want to access the 3rd byte of a 4-byte number, doing the following is perfectly legitimate:

```
%bytes = bitcast i32* %num to i8*
%third_byte = getelementptr i8* %bytes, i32 2
```

Just keep in mind the endianess when you do stuff like that.

And yes, you can use this technique to obtain pointers to specific locations in an array and `store` and `load` values from there, enabling you to do duplicate your entire example.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible in C/C++ too. You should not assign an uninitialized variable to another variable. It invokes **undefined behavior**. `*B` and `*c` are uninitialized.

Comment: *"You can't"* I think this is very restrictive language, because you can do it, but has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Manu343726; Agreed. Changed that.

Comment: Ok, however if B and C were initialized, it would have a well defined behavior?

Comment: @redratio1 in that case, it breaks the [strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) I think.

Comment: @redratio1; I think what you want to do is `B = A` and `C = (A+4)`, isn't it?

Comment: @haccks; Basically what I want to do is take a 32 bit result from a previous hash, and a max 2 x 32 bit value. Have them in an array so I can walk through it byte by byte.